# How to center text horizontally & vertically within dotted border

Tags: html, css

I need to center some text between a dotted border vertically and horizontally as in below image :

[image]

I have a [very simple fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eCUv9/2/) which attempts to achieve this.

How can the css be amended to appear as attached screenshot ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eCUv9/16/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS positioning to do this...

Check this out :

**[My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aHNh6/1/)** (Horizontal)

**[My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aHNh6/2/)** (Vertical)

Comment: is it possible to not change the background colour but at same time border is not appearing behind text like this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/aHNh6/4/?

Comment: @user701254 no you'll have to use `background-color` abd did you mean not appearing or appearing?

Comment: I mean, I'd like to keep the same background color as what the text is being drawn on but at same time no see a border appearing behind the text. Hope this makes more sense. I can just change the background color of the text to match the background color of where the text is being drawn

Comment: there is a border appearing behind the text "TEXT GOES HERE" unless a background color is set. I dont want to set the background color but at same time ensure a border is not drawn through the text. Thanks anyway, you answered my question

Comment: ya now I got you, and no I understood what you want but you need to give a background color to the text

Comment: .wrap {
    border-top: 2px dotted #000;
    position: relative;
    margin: 25px auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.text {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    top: -13px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
}

Just made these changes

Answer (score 2):

You can try floating a div with text and give it margin to place it over the border.

**HTML**

```
<div id="dotted">
    <div id="text">Text goes here.</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#dotted {
    border-top:1px dotted #000;
    padding:10px;
}

#text {
    float:left;
    padding:0 10px 0 10px;
    margin:-20px 0 0 30px;
    background:#fff;
}
```

​
JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aBDjY/2/

Comment: is it possible to not change the background colour but at same time border is not appearing behind text like this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aBDjY/3/

Comment: @user701254. In short, no. In this method I am moving the text over the border. If no background color is set, then the line will appear through the text. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/lukas2012/aHNh6/5/

You can also work with a pseudeoelement (:after)

and use `text-align: center` with `display: inline-block`

This way it will work with any text and your layout will not be irritated by moving a relative element around

To keep the background color dynamic just use `background-color: inherit;`

```
.wrap{
    position: relative;
    margin: 100px auto;
    width: 500px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ff0;

}
.wrap:after {
    content: '';
    border-top:1px dotted #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;

}

.text {
    background-color: inherit;
    position: relative;
    margin:0  auto;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 1;
}
​
```